# Increment last digit of double value

Tags: java

I have a double variable which is like 80.14666666666668 then I used floor function to truncate it till 8 digits like 80.14666666. Now I want to increment this value and get answer as 80.14666667

Comment: Why don't you just round?

Comment: Why don't you ask question? :)

Comment: I would suggest "add 0.00000001" to it but I fear the downvotes...

Comment: "Now I want to increment this value and get answer as 80.14666667." *You have our permission to proceed.*

Comment: What if the last digit is a 9?

Answer (score 2):

You may not be aware of the true nature of `double`s. They do not have "digits"; they are a compact binary encoding of rational numbers. Therefore you'll find it very difficult to programmatically determine what is "the last digit" of a `double`.

If your specific need is just rounding, then use the `round` function instead of `truncate`; otherwise consider using a `BigDecimal`, which truly represents a number with decimal digits.

Answer (score 0):

A quick approach would be:

```
double myNumber = 80.14666666;
myNumber += (1 / 10^8); // = 80.14666667
```

Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

The double does not actually contain the exact value that you imagine it does. This is because the underlying field is held as a binary number and cannot contain tenths due to the factor of 1/5.

Instead you could use new BigDecimal("80.14666666") and increment that by new BigDecimal("0.00000001").

Note that I am passing a string to initialise this object. If you pass a double the BigDecimal will be initialised according to the value of the double which as mentioned does not contain the exact value that you imagine it does.

Answer (score 0):

Just add 0.00000001 to the number.

However, floating point values are not very well suited for counting like that. Each time you increment it, you will be adding a discrepancy, because numbers like that are only represented approximately in the floating point number.

If you want to increment numbers, use an integer instead. Multiply the number by 100000000 and convert it to an integer so that you get 8014666666. Now you can increment the integer by one without introducing any errors. Keep the integer for incrementing, and convert it into the floating point format as needed by dividing by 100000000. The floating point value will of course still have it's limitation in precision, but each one will be the result of converting from its integer counterpart, and the integer value doesn't have any precision issues, so you won't accumulate errors each time you increment.